# Equicontinuity of functions

Tags: real-analysis

How can I prove the equicontinuity of this set without considering the convergence?
$$
(-1)^k\times x+\frac {1}{k}\times\sin(kx)     \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x\in [0,2], k=0,1,2... 
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_k(x)=(-1)^kx+\frac1k\sin(kx)$. You want to show that for all $\epsilon>0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta\implies |f_k(x)-f_k(y)|<\epsilon$. We have
$$\begin{align}
|f_k(x)-f_k(y)|&=\left|(-1)^k(x-y)+\frac{1}{k}(\sin(kx)-\sin(ky))\right|\\
&\le |x-y|+\frac{1}{k}|\sin(kx)-\sin(ky)|\\
&= |x-y|+\frac{1}{k}\left|\int_x^y\frac{d}{dt}\sin(kt)dt\right|\\
&= |x-y|+\frac{1}{k}\left|\int_x^yk\cos(kt)dt\right|\\
&\le |x-y|+\int_x^y|\cos(kt)|dt \;\text{(assuming WLOG that $x<y$)}\\
&\le |x-y|+\int_x^y1dt\\
&= 2|x-y|
\end{align}$$
thus it suffices to take $\delta=\epsilon/2$.

Comment: Thank you! MVT can be used as well then.